# Mystery application?

Tags: macos, applications, video, xcode

Okay, so I was watching a WWDC video a while ago, and they were doing a demonstration on how to implement some code into your app...

And as they were demonstrating the code, the guy who was doing the demo was pulling blocks of code from a small window in the bottom right corner of the screen.

I thought that this would be a useful application to have (as I am an apple developer myself) and I thought it would save me a lot of time...

The only problem is I have no idea what this application is called and so do not have any information about it...

All I know is that the WWDC video is called "Optimize your earning power with iAd" and that the application in question is shown at 37:50 in the aforementioned video.

If someone could point me in the right direction as to where I should start my search I would be most thankful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The little text snippet application they are using is called [DemoMonkey](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/DemoMonkey/Introduction/Intro.html). It's actually a sample code project on developer.apple.com from 2010.

Comment: there are a LOT of bugs in the code... Is there another application in existence that is similar to this?

Comment: I'm not really sure if there are similar applications. If you feel like it could you log some of those bugs [here](https://github.com/wooster/DemoMonkey/issues) and I'll see if I can fix them. :)